# Publishing c# app with clickonce security throws invalid value for osversion error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to publish a c# wpf app to an unc path. The app runs fine when clickonce security is disabled, but while publishing the clickonce security gets enabled and it throws the error invalid osversion under:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

I tried to make sense out of it, but I still have a long way to go in terms of understanding the properties.

Would someone with more insight be so kind to enlighten me, what is happening and maybe how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So for those who encounter a similar situation:

There seems to be an error which is only thrown for clickonce applications.

The "workaround" for this curiosity is to locate your .csproj file and open it with a text editor.

It will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
 .....
</PropertyGroup>
.....
.....
```

Now just add OSVersion above the closing statement of the first PropertyGroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
 .....
<OSVersion/>
</PropertyGroup>
.....
.....
```

Hope this helps someone and here is the source of the provided information:
https://romiller.com/2008/05/05/invalid-value-for-osversion/

fyi: don't publish to a folder with an "&" in the path.

Comment: Careful : this can destroy an entire solution when entered wrongly. Lucky it was just a test project to try out click once. Thanks for the suggestion.